# Unity 3D - Move 2D sprite around the screen edges clockwise/anticlockwise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I was wondering if anyone knows the best way to get a 2d sprite to go around in a clockwise or anti clockwise motion around the screen edges in Unity? (Snake like motion)

I have looked at ways of determining the screen size but in terms of a actually getting my sprite moving I am out of luck.

Comment: Honestly there's like a zillion posts; samples; and articles on Unity3D not to mention the bizillions on YouTube

Answer (score 0):

> getting my sprite moving

```
Update() {
    var target = new Vector3(10, 10, 0);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target, Time.deltaTime);
}
```

This will move your object to the position (10, 10, 0) over time. But, like the comment said, there are a gazillion tutorials that can help you more, and this will also improve your Google Fu.